# Trefoil Knot Group

Tags: group-theory, knot-theory, group-presentation

I am studying Knot theory and have gone through the Wirtinger Presentation for the Knot Group. However, I come across the different(at least for me) way of finding the Knot Group. Instead of labeling curves  [Bela Bollobas](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461299691) is labeling the closed region and then come up with the presentation 
$$<a,b,c,d \mid ad^{-1}b, cd^{-1}a, cbd^{-1}>$$

[image]

I didn't get how this presentation we got with the given labeling, or I say what is this method called and how we write presentation of knot group via this method.

Comment: There are two parts to this, one easy and one difficult. The easy part is to see that the given relations are true. The difficult part is to see that the given relations suffice to give the correct group. Can you at least see how $ad^{-1}b=e$? (And is the last one supposed to be $cd^{-1}b$?)

Comment: I didn't get how the given relation work? Is $ad^{-1}b$ operation of region or curves?

Comment: Any letter represents a loop going through that region once (in your favourite positive direction; mine is down in this case, as is the author's) and no other region. So $ad^{-1}b$ is a loop going down through $a$, up through $d$ and down through $b$ (and then to the side, to join up with itself outside the trefoil). This would be a lot easier if I could paint a picture, sorry.

Comment: The name of this presentation is the Dehn presentation of the knot group. See these links: [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/knot+group), a [paper by Jim Hoste](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c2e8/09795d593c5753e01ff377b3f5621b5d8a39.pdf), and a [paper by Scott Carter, Dan Silver, and Susan Williams](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5378.pdf).

Comment: The problem with Dehn's presentation (as opposed to Wirtinger's) is that it's significantly harder to see how to construct, and work with, covering spaces of the knot. This may well be a fruitful (and largely neglected) line of inquiry.